# The nice and round sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I have thought up a sequence, and I name it the nice and round sequence. Its first 10 numbers are

> 15773, 29694, 165083, 276316, 496325, 498512, 702504, 719466, 808667, 826245
>
> What is its pattern?

---

Hint 1:

> More numbers of the sequence can be found in this spreadsheet
>
>  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150JlMSb_Fd6v4z2wElkdYTgo54e8CiBWS1pP0pnp4X4/edit?usp=sharing

Hint 2:

> I do not think there is a formula to compute the terms.

Hint 3:

> What number is considered nice by the internet denizens? What number is related to round things?

Comment: Does Hint 2 imply that the sequence is [uncomputable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function), or simply mean that there isn't an *arithmetic* formula? (Related: [a small set of arithmetic operations can cover very wide range of computable functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204949/78410))

Comment: @Bubbler It can be found using a computer program, but there is no explicit formula (I think), just like the sequence of primes numbers, which there is no formula to compute it but you may write a program to find prime numbers.

Comment: Okay, that answers my question. Btw, people have come up with [purely arithmetic formula for primality testing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170398/78410) and such, so "there's no formula to compute it" is quite stronger statement than it sounds.

Comment: @Bubbler Primality testing is not quite the same as a formula that generates the sequence of prime numbers. Somehow relevant is [this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) where there are some interesting formulas, both recurrent and non-recurrent.

Comment: Hint 3 makes me think of fvkgl-avar (gur "avpr" zrzr) naq cv vf trarenyyl eryngrq gb pvepyrf but so far no luck making it work :<

Comment: @Pepper Vf gurer nalguvat avpre guna fvkgl-avar?

Comment: $\pi$ is round???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is made up of the

> positions of the sequence `69420` ([nice](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/69)) within the digits of Pi after the decimal place (round).

The next number in the sequence (excluding those in the hint within the question) is

> 3022306, as the 3022306th, 3022307th, ... and 3022310th digits of Pi after the decimal place are `69420`.